# Programmatically get 14 hive path in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I need to get 14 hive path using code in C#.net.

can any one tell me how can I do this?

Comment: Do you want the hive path or really want to access e.g. Controltemplates / Layouts?

Comment: i dont want to access this path. i need to 14 hive layouts path programatically(physical path).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can access the physical path using `SPUtility` - the web path by looking at the `SPWeb` object.

Using `SPUtility` to get the SetupPath of Sharepoint like so:

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;
string spSetupPath = SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath(string.Empty);
//e.g. returns "C:\Program Files\Common files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14
```

- [MSDN documentation SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.getgenericsetuppath%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
- [Example usages of SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath (e.g. getting the templates dir)](http://www.devexpertise.com/2009/02/13/getting-the-default-sharepoint-installation-path/)

Or you can use SPWeb's server relative URL method:

```
using Microsoft.Sharepoint;
string spServerURL = SPWeb.ServerRelativeUrl;
```

[MSDN documentation SPWeb.ServerRelativeURL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.serverrelativeurl.aspx)

Also have an [overview of the Sharepoint 2010 14 hive structure](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/06/07/14-hive-and-other-sharepoint-2010-directories/).

Comment: for this string spSetupPath = SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath; i got the error:Cannot convert method group 'GetGenericSetupPath' to non-delegate type 'string'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Comment: had an error in the code, you need to add `(string.Empty)` after the method - check out the example usages of SPUtility link I posted.